# Check if there is a consonant in a string in java

Tags: java

So I am writing a program that is the game called pig latin (You can check Wikipedia for the rules, but it consits of taking the first consonants and moving them to the back of the word and adding -ay). I need to check the word has any consonants in the beginning of the word . If it has a or more consants the it needs to get the substring starting at the first consonant and ending at the last consonant before a vowel.

```
public void isConsonant(String word){
    char[] consonants = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'
            , 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z' };
    char[] StringArray = word.toCharArray();
    for(int dex = 0; dex < StringArray.length; dex++ ){
        char current = StringArray[dex];
    }
}
```

Here is an example:

The word 'glove' should become oveglay . My program outputs 'lovegay'.

Here is my program (minus `imports` and `GUI` stuff):

```
public class PigLatin extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextField word = new JTextField(25);
    JButton GO = new JButton("Go");
    JLabel output = new JLabel();
    String CharNum1;
    String CharNum2;

    //The frame setup should be here

    public void isConsonant(String verify) {
        char[] consonants = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z' };
        char[] StringArray = verify.toCharArray();
        for (int dex = 0; dex < StringArray.length; dex++) {
            char current = StringArray[dex];
        }
    }

    public void game() {
        // The actual word
        String word2 = word.getText();

        // The first character
        CharNum1 = word2.substring(0, 2);
        CharNum2 = word2.substring(1, word2.length());

        // Remove the first char
        // String RevampedWord = word2.replace(CharNum1, "");
        String finalWord = CharNum2 + "-" + CharNum1 + "ay";
        output.setText(finalWord);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        game();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        PigLatin pig = new PigLatin();
    }
}
```

So my question is weather it is possible to see if a String contains consonats and make a substring of the first consonant to the first consonant before a vowel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: College assignment? :)

Comment: All that GUI stuff seems to be irrelevant to the problem. Try writing a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/), people will be much more likely to read it and help you if they don't have to figure out whih part of your code relates to the problem.

Comment: I really don't understand why people fill their code with new line breaks. Why not just keep it small and simple? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of possibly doing what you want that is a little intriguing:

Supposing that you are turning `word` into pig latin, what about using `word.split("[aeiouAEIOU]", 2)`? Looking at the docs for `split`, it'll match the regex exactly once, so the array of strings returned will be split around the first vowel in the word. You can then put those pieces back into the right order based on whether the first vowel was the first char, last char, somewhere in between, or even nowhere to be found (remember, not all words contain one of those five vowels).

(Note that `split` will remove the first vowel if it finds it, so you'll have to use `word` to get that vowel back, but the size of the first piece will also be that vowel's index into `word`.)

Comment: +1 This helped me so much! I will post my solution in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You're barking up the wrong tree... use regex:

To extract all consonants up to the first vowel:

```
String initialConsonants = str.replaceAll("([^aeiouAEIOU]*).*", "$1");
```

To extract just the consonants:

```
String onlyConsonants = str.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "");
```

or if you really need to know if the text is all consonants:

```
boolean isAllConsonants = str.matches("[^aeiouAEIOU]+");
```

Comment: I don't understand the statements.

Comment: You could read the javadoc for `String.replaceAll()`, but essentially it uses regex to find and replace. Here I used it to remove (by replacing with a blank) all vowel characters. The `matches()` method also uses regex - here I've used it to assert the entire string is comprised only of non-vowels. A tutorial on regex is beyond the scope of this forum, but I encourage you to learn it - it's a powerful weapon.

Comment: I don't exactly see how this could help. I am not saying your awnser is useless because it helped solve another problem but how could I use it after that? I need all the consonants up to the first vowel. Is there a way to find the position of the first vowel? Thanks

Comment: I've added the line you need to get all consonants before the first vowel (if any - it will return a blank if the first letter is a vowel)

Comment: This answer doesn't seem all that useful for directly applying it to the question at hand, but it was very useful for the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing big , have a boolean function that would check in that char is vowel

eg

```
public static boolean isVowel(final char ch) {
return ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u';

}
```

Check for each and every character and then you can easily code it out.

Comment: This would work as long as you can guarantee no special characters (eg dashes)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it, I erased your `isConsonant` function and made a new one to get the first portion of the String that only contains constants.

The game function is modified with this change:

```
public String getFirstConsonants(String verify) {
    List<Character> vowels = Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'); // better finding vowels (faster)

    String firstString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < verify.length(); i++) {
        if (!vowels.contains(verify.charAt(i)))
            firstString += verify.charAt(i); // we found a constant
        else
            break; // we found a vowel, we have already our string
        }

    return firstString;
}

public void game() {
    // The actual word
    String word2 = word.getText();

    // Lets find the first consonants
    String firstString = getFirstConsonants(word2);

    String finalWord = word2.substring(firstString.length()) + "-" + firstString + "ay";
    output.setText(finalWord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some 1-line routines to detect if a certain character is a consonant or vowel:

```
private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    return "aeiouAEIOU".contains(String.valueOf(c));
}

private static boolean isConsonant(char c) {
    return "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ".contains(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

Comment: seems to be missing this part: "make a substring of the first consonant to the first consonant before a vowel."